# Vue 3 what is the class-Based API, function-based API, Reactivity API and composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

When I started working with vue 3, I saw these notions :

- Object-based API
- Function-based API
- Class-Based API
- Composition API
- Options API
- Reactivity API

Can some one tell us the definitions of these?

Update 2021

I added Options API and Reactivity API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that the main docs mention *Options-based*, and not *Object-based*, but even in references by Evan, they seem to be interchangeable.

**Option-based API is Class-based** and **Function-based API is Composition API**.

*Option-based* vs *Function-based* express, what I would call, the theoretical model of how to differentiate the APIs. Whereas *Class-based* vs *Composition* differentiate between the implementation.

### Options-based/Class-based API

You have the old way used by vue1 and vue2, called class-based, which is referred to as Option-based API.

The naming implies that the component is defined by options. You may think of the options as `data`, `computed`, `methods` etc... They define how a component works by using a set of pre-defined options that you overload.

The downside of this way of defining functionality is that you have the actual component logic distributed between various "options", which makes it harder to understand from the code what the component actually does.

### Function-based/Composition API

Function implies that we're declaring *functionality* of the component (not that it's using functional components). The Composition API makes the code easier to reuse (since you don't need to tightly-couple aspects of functionality to a component) and easier to read and maintain (since you can encapsulate functionality in smaller, dedicated units)

Comment: OMG the names!  It's 3 paragraphs just straighten out all of the repeated names of the same things.  The docs for Vuejs 3 seem to only discuss composition API, and ignore the options-based one.  But it seems like you can still use it?  vue-cli seems to still write out templates in options based create greater confusion.  And while much text is written to extoll the virtues of composition API I can't see how it enables any of the platitudes foisted upon it.   "easier to read and maintain" seems to be a question of taste more than an objective truth.